# Auto-incrementing the value of a model field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

i want to ask a question that how can i increment a model field in django.
lets suppose i have a model called

> class my bookmarks(requests):
>
> ```
>   url=models.URLField()
>   popularity=models.IntegerField()
> ```

and then by using Django template
i have

> > ## bookmarks.html
> >
> > {% for database in list_tagg %}
>
> URL:{{database.url}}
>
> > POPULARITY: {{database.popularity}}
>
> {% endfor %}

Now: if anyone clicks on the link (i.e. the URL field in the bookmarks.html page) I would like that the popularity should be increased by 1. How can i do so? Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use F-fields ,)

```
from django.db.models import F

b = Bookmark.objects.get(pk=id_retrieved)
b.popularity = F('popularity') + 1
b.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to implement an Ajax call to connect to the server and record the click.  For example, using jQuery, you can have this JS function called on every click:

```
function incrementPopCounter(pop_id) {
    $.ajax({type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/pop/increment',
            data: 'id=' + pop_id,
            success: function(data) {
               if(data.result == 'OK') {
                   // handle success
               } else {
                   // handle failure
               }
            }
           });
    return false;
}
```

The Django view to handle this could look like this:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
...
def increment_pop(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if 'pop_id' in request.POST and request.POST['pop_id']:
            try:
                pop = Bookmark.objects.get(pk=request.POST['pop_id'])
            except Bookmark.DoesNotExist:
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result': 'No bookmark by that id found.'}),
                                    mimetype='application/json')
            pop.popularity = F('popularity') + 1
            pop.save()
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result': 'OK'}),
                                mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result': 'Unable to identify the requested bookmark.'}),
                                mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Almad's answer could be simplified to the following:

```
from django.db.models import F

Bookmark.objects.get(pk=id_retrieved).update(popularity=F('popularity') + 1)
```